# LL1 grammar for arithmetic expressions and assignments

Tags: parsing, ocaml, grammar, ambiguous-grammar

I would like to design an LL1 grammar for arithmetic equations and variable assignments. I began with this grammar:

I have a nonambiguous grammar for arithmetic expressions:

```
E → T E’
E’ →  | + E
T → id T’
T’ →  | * T
```

However, I'm not sure how to incorporate variable assignments into the E productions.

How I tried previously was:

```
    stmt -> assignment SEMI | RETURN stmt_prime 
   | LBRACE stmt_list RBRACE 
   | IF LPAREN assignment RPAREN stmt stmt_prime_prime 
   | FOR LPAREN assignment SEMI assignment SEMI assignment RPAREN stmt | 
    stmt_prime -> SEMI | -> assignment SEMI
    stmt_prime_prime -> NOELSE 
    | ELSE stmt
    assignment -> ID typ ASSIGN expr | expr  
    expr -> TE* 
    E* -> + TE* | -TE* | epsilon
    T -> FT*
    T* -> * FT* | / FT* | epsilon
    F -> (E) | int_literal | TRUE | FALSE
```

Comment: First of all your grammar is not just left-recursive, but also ambiguous (because it leaves the precedence of operators unclear). You should remove the ambiguity before the left recursion. Secondly: Are you following a course or learning on your own? If you're not specifically supposed to do it this way, I'd recommend using EBNF instead of BNF, which allows you to define rules for infix operators and things like `stmt_list` much more succinctly using the repetition operator.

Comment: I'm taking a course - creating a grammar that has assignments and arithmetic expressions isnt required by the assignment, I'm just hopeful I can figure it out.

Comment: @sepp2k is what I updated with any better?

Comment: Do you really want `typ` to be part of assignments? It wasn't in the original version of your post (and it isn't in any real language I've ever seen). Also: I assume `F` should also contain a production `F -> ID`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
assignment -> ID ASSIGN expr | expr
```

(I'm ignoring the `typ` part because I assume it got there by accident)

The problem here is that both `ID ASSIGN expr` and `expr` could start with an `ID` (or at least they could if `T` contained `ID` as an option, which I assume was the intention), so this isn't LL(1). It is LL(2) though, so if you're fine with that, you can just add an `andalso next_token = ASSIGN` to the `if` condition in your parser and be done with it.

If you do need it to be LL(1), you'll have to adjust the language allowed by your parser, I'm afraid (that is, there is no LL(1) grammar that matches exactly the same language as your current grammar). One easy way out would be to simply add a keyword like `SET` before assignment, though admittedly that's ugly.

The other alternative would be to allow arbitrary expressions as the left operand of `=`, making your assignment rule:

```
assignment -> exp (ASSIGN exp)?
```

Which is LL(1). The downside of this is that it allows a lot of non-sensical code such as `1+2 := 42`, but you can fix that outside of the grammar. That is, your code for parsing assignments can simply call `parse_exp` and then, if the next token is an `ASSIGN` and the expression returned by `parse_exp` is not just an identifier, raise an error that the left-side of an assignment must be an identifier.